# Ошибка "Specified locale name is too long"

Tags: php

> `Warning: setlocale() [function.setlocale]: Specified locale name is too long in /home/user4092/html/XO4U.BIZ/simpla/ImportAdmin.php on line 25`

Что это за ошибка?

Comment: проверь 25 строку в файле ImportAdmin.php

Comment: проверял вот она   setlocale(LC_ALL, $old_locale);

Comment: Указанный язык слишком длинное имя (перевод ошибки)

Comment: так что исправить то нужно?

Comment: В качестве локали функция ожидает что то в виде 'ru_RU' или 'de_DE'. А что у Вас там - непонятно, но кто мешает распечатать с помощью `echo($old_locale);` и посмотреть?

Comment: вы скажите что сделать надо я не понял о чем вы....echo($old_locale); куда это7

Comment: например перед строкой `setlocale(LC_ALL, $old_locale);` вставьте строку `echo("***".$old_locale."***");`. Теперь открываете страницу в броузере, смотрите исходный код и ищете эти `***нечто***`.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8`

вот что мне теперь делать?

Comment: смотреть, откуда эта строка там взялась.

Comment: ну я вв этом не сильно шарю...скажите как?

Comment: Название вопроса фантастическое.

Comment: так что делать?